# Python 3, receive a string as an argument without any return value

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, arguments, return-value

I'm learning Python and have been taking an online class. This class was very basic and I am know trying to continue my studies elsewhere. Stackoverflow.com has helped me a great deal. In the online course we didn't cover a lot about return statements, which I am now trying to learn. I would like to do something very basic, so I was thinking of creating a program that would receive a string as an argument without having any return value. I want the user to type a word that will be shown with characters or symbols between every letter.

Example
User types in the word Python.
The word will be shown as =P=y=t=h=o=n= or -P-y-t-h-o-n- or maybe with * between every letter.

Is this an easy task? Can someone help me how to go about doing this?
Thank you.
Joel

Comment: Have you seen strings as list already?

Comment: Yes, a little bit.

Comment: Well as Ryan said, you can use `join` but you could go "handmade" and iterate through the input string, have a second string and construct it with each character and the character you want, then display the constructed string.

Comment: @ThomasKowalski Hmmm... I'm thinking I could learn more that way maybe? Could you give me an example? I'm VERY new to programming and all the new terms and words are still flying around inside my brain giving me a bit of a headache. :)

Comment: I added an answer, without giving the solution, you should be able to get a clear understanding of the idea.

Comment: Yeah it was perfect! Thank you so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it yourself, you can go through your string like this:

```
my_string = "Python"
for letter in my_string:
    # do something with the letter
    print(letter)
```

This will print each letter in your word. What *you* want to do is having a new string with your desired character. You probably know you can concatenate (append) two strings in this way :

```
str1 = "hello"
str2 = "world"
str3 = str1 + str2
print(str3) #helloworld
```

So to do what you'd like to do, you can see each letter as a substring of your main string, and your desired character (for example `*`) as another string, and build a result string in that way.

```
inputString = "Python"
result = ""
myChar = "*"
for letter in inputString:
    # build your result
    build = build + letter
print(build)
```

This will just copy `inputString` into `result`, though I think you'll have understood how to use it in order to add your custom chars between the letters.

Comment: Wow, that's a really good explanation. Thank you good sir! I will play around a bit! Thank you for taking the time to help me out and to explain it properly!

Answer (score 0):

Yes python makes this sort of string manipulation very easy (some other languages... not so much). Look up the standard `join` function in the python docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fancy_print(s, join_char='-'):
    # split string into a list of characters
    letters = list(s)
    # create joined string
    output = join_char + join_char.join(letters) + join_char
    # show it
    print(output)
```

then

```
>>> fancy_print("PYTHON")
-P-Y-T-H-O-N-

>>> fancy_print("PYTHON", "*")
*P*Y*T*H*O*N*
```

Comment: Interesting answer to give a beginner the solution to the problem he's trying to resolve on his own...